# как в java проверить вводные данные на тип

Tags: java

Подскажите новичку, как в java проверить вводные данные на тип? нужно получить вводные данные типа int, а не какие другие. Спасибо, заранее)
P.S.:я немного подправил код, были "косяки", но если честно проблему не решил с вводом данных от пользователя, но всех кто откликнулся на просьбу благодарю.

```
import java.util.*;//подключаем ввод данных от пользователя
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner value_1= new Scanner(System.in);//ввод числа от пользователя, с клавиатуры

        System.out.println("Guess the intended number from 20 to 100.");//угадай задуманное число от 20 до 100
        int value_2=0;
        //заводим цикл while(), который будет проверять вводимые данные на угадывание числа
         value_2 = value_1.nextInt();
         while(value_2!=64){

         if(value_2 < 20){System.out.println("The number must be more than 20 and less than 100.");}//Число должно быть более 20 и менее 100.
         else if(value_2>100)
           {System.out.println("The number must be less than 100.");}//Число должно быть меньше 100.
         else{
           System.out.println("You have not guessed the intended number!"+"\n"+value_2+" is not intended number. Than try again.");} // Вы не угадали задуманное число,попробуйте еще
                //на выводе программа подсказывает число пользователя больше или меньше нашего задуманного числа
                if(value_2 > 64)
                {System.out.println("   hint: "+value_2+"  more than our number!\n");}//подсказка:... такое-то число больше нашего
                else
                {System.out.println("   hint: "+value_2+"  less than our number!\n");}//подсказка...такое-то число меньше нашего
           value_2 = value_1.nextInt();// присваиваем полученное число переменной value_2
         }//проверяем вводимое число и возвращаемся снова пока не угадано число 64           

         System.out.println("Сongratulations! You guessed it, this number is 51!");//Поздравляем! Вы угадали, это число  64!
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = 0;
while(value != 64){
    String strValue = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!strValue.matches("-?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели не число");
        continue;
    } else {
        value = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Знак забыли....

Comment: Поправил) Учитываем знак)

Comment: а остальные знаки?...

Comment: Да и вообще по-хорошему надо делать nextInt и отлавливать исключение.

Comment: Ну напишите свой вариант ответа, кто Вам мешает?

Comment: Мне лень........

Comment: Дело в том, что nextInt работает не совсем так, как хотелось бы. Если зациклить с nextInt и в обработке исключения написать continue(для того, чтобы программа возвращала нас в начало цикла до тех пока, пока пользователь не введёт именно цифру) и при этом ввести букву, то программа даже не будет ждать следующего ввода, а будет просто рисовать исключения один за другим, т.к. в сканере висит введённая буква. Как вариант, можно в catch'e вызывать next(), чтобы чистить сканер, но как по мне, это не очень разумно. По-моему регулярки это не самое плохое решение в данной ситуации.

Comment: @АндрейГалкин, здесь не получится вводить несколько чисел в одной строке.

Comment: @АндрейГалкин, ну конечно, есть ведь hasNextInt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925047/how-to-check-the-input-is-an-integer-or-not-in-java

Comment: @КириллМалышев, а в чем разница? hasNextInt тормозит пользователя и ждёт ввод. Видит, что там не int и выдаёт нам esle, в котором мы выводим пользователю, что он ввёл не число и continue возвращает его в начало цикла. Но когда он на второй итерации дойдёт до hasNextInt, то он не будет ждать ввода, а сразу выдаст false, т.к. в сканере до сих пор находится эта буква и будет просто по кругу выдавать пользователю сообщение о том, что он ввёл не цифру. Как вариант, можно в esle добавить метод next, который будет чистить сканер, но в чем тогда разница между hasNextInt и моим вышеописанным try-catch?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, в данной задаче, по моему, и не требуется вводить несколько чисел в одной строке.